# Вывод canvas на рабочий стол

Tags: java

Нужно написать программу, которая выводит падение снега на рабочем столе? Как сделать в джава, чтобы это было на рабочем столе? )))))

Comment: Не уверен, что джава тут - хороший выбор...

Comment: Не надо закрывать. Вопрос нормальный. Тут надо ответить о параметрах создания окна, когда оно попадает в слой рабочего стола.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, хва закрывать всё подряд. Чем вопрос не угодил?

Comment: Вам только именно определение, чтоб только на рабочем столе или еще алгоритм снега и код для его выпадения? Непонятно.

Comment: @Qwertiy хватит поддерживать непонятно что.....вопрос неясен, что конкретно имеется в виду. Нужно уточнение

Comment: Создать прозрачное окно, без рамок, распахнуть его на весь экран (максимизировать). И рисовать на нём падающий снег. Могу на C# пример набросать.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov а такое окно не перекроет доступ к нажатию на значки рабочего стола?

Comment: @CodeGust - Перекроет. Зато снег на рабочем столе, зима, мороз, новый год...

Comment: @ Alexander Petrov
Ну так это, получается, экранную Java-заставку (screensaver) делать нужно по сути))