# Работа с Bitmap в C#

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

С помощью какого метода можно обратиться к уже существующему изображению, для последующего изменения(конкретно нужно открыть изображение,нарисовать на нём пикселями что-либо методом SetPixel(); , сохранить)

Comment: Вы не могли бы дополнить свой вопрос?(т.к. сейчас не понятно, что вы хотите сделать).

Comment: Что используете: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov WF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужен класс [`Bitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx). У него есть методы `GetPixel` и `SetPixel`.

Например:

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(path);
bmp.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.Black);
bmp.Save(newpath);
```

Для быстрой обработки многих пикселей вам понадобится [`LockBits`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: А сам он до этого не догадался? Думаю, надо что-то другое.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну пусть задаст уточняющие вопросы. Я плохой телепат сегодня. Ну и пусть поиск приводит сюда лучше :)

Comment: Лучше б на http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594977/178988 ответил - там интереснее.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Java? o_O

Comment: Скорее winapi на джаве))) Зато вопрос интересный. Но его уже почти закрыли. И вообще, ты чего в чате переоткрытия не появляешься?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Кстати да, надо бы появиться :)

Answer (score 1):

Загрузка изображения вроде так:

```
Bitmap image = Bitmap(/*fileName*/);
```

---

Вариант без блокирования файла:

```
public static Bitmap LoadBitmap(string fileName)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        return new Bitmap(fs);
}
```

[Источник](https://habrahabr.ru/post/196578/) - тут кстати много интересной информации.